# How can I set a letter in a equation both small and bold

Tags: equations, fontsize

I want to set the "\widehat{\mathbf{x}}" part smaller but I've no idea how can I do it. Any suggesting would be very grateful.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\section{one}

\[
\mathbf{A}\cdot \widehat{\mathbf{x}}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Smaller? In what sense?

Comment: @egreg Yes smaller indeed. I would like the "x" (with hat) is much smaller than the "A". Better only reach to the half height of the "A". Because big "x" (with hat) and small one has different mathematical meaning in my lecture, but I cannot differentiate them in Latex since I'm new to it.

Comment: I'd find very difficult to distinguish between “small x” and “large x” when reading.

Comment: @egreg which means there is nothing I can do about it? big and bold x with hat and small bold one has a big different appearance is very important for the lecture. So you are telling me Latex might no be a very smart choice for this?

Comment: I'm not saying that LaTeX is unable to do it; I'm thinking to people who want to understand your lectures and will not notice the difference in size.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\smallmath}[1]{%
  {\scriptstyle#1}%
}

\begin{document}
$\mathbf{A}\widehat{\mathbf{x}}$ is different from $\mathbf{A}\smallmath{\widehat{\mathbf{x}}}$
\end{document}
```

But the result is quite disappointing, as I was sure of: no reader will appreciate the difference.

[image]

If you change from `\scriptstyle` to `\scriptscriptstyle` it's even worse:

[image]

Comment: Hi egred! that's the exact result I've been looking for! Thanks a lot!

Comment: may be you need to do \newcommand{\sx}{{\scriptstyle\widehat{\mathbf{x}}}}
\newcommand{\bx}{\widehat{\mathbf{x}}} and use it \bx for big x and \sx for small x

Comment: @touhami That's left as an exercise. `;-)`

Answer (score 3):

You can try with `\medmath` (80 % of `\displaystyle`) from `nccmath`, which is more acceptable:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, nccmath}
\begin{document}

\[
\mathbf{A}\cdot \widehat{\mathbf{x}}\qquad\mathbf{A}\cdot \medmath{\widehat{\mathbf{x}}} \qquad\mathbf{A}\cdot {\scriptstyle\widehat{\mathbf{x}}}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How can somebody distinguish between the first and the secon example?

Comment: I don't understand… The  center `widehat{x}` has a size between \display style on the left and \scriptstyle on the right. Isn't it visible?

Comment: It's visible, but just because the symbols are next to each other; I'm talking about somebody who has to read a document where the two x's are not next to each other: it will be really difficult to tell them apart.